# How to skip a class which is mentioned in testNG.xml through programs

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a testNG.xml file which contains 10 classes, but I have a list which contains 4 classes. I just need to compare, and execute the 4 test cases which is in list instead of executing all 10 in testNg.xml. Is it possible ? give me some idea that how to skip 6 classes in testNG.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As up on request, below is the simple way to create testng.xml by excel data.

Let us assume in excel file, sheet 0, i am going to write all the classes with status Y/N means executable or not. so first row (i=0) in sheet is nothing but having header as test case in cell 0 and Executable in cell 1.

If cell 1 of any row from i=1 nothing but for class having executable as Y, then i need to add this class to my test, then this test to my suite, finally need to execute this suite.

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("TmpSuite");

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("TmpTest");
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

    FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\TestCases.xlsx"));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for(int i=1; i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++){

        if(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equals("Y")){


            classes.add(new XmlClass(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue()));

        }

    }

    test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you what to execute required classes, then include those in TestNG.xml file, as i am not sure why you are not able to try this.

Generally i will prefer reading required classes which is required for execution from excel file and building xml file by scripting. info [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Anyhow as per your requirement, you can use skipexecution to skip the test as per you condition.

```
@Test
public void testCaseSkipException(){
    //if my condition is true then i will going to below skipException to skip execution
       if(your_condition){
        throw new SkipException("Skipping this exception");
     }
    }
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: I knew there will be a possible to create a testNG.xml dynamically. But is there any way to create a dynamic testNG.xml through excel sheet data? any examples please. Since We're executing the scripts through testNG.xml I'm not sure how make dynamic testng.xml and then make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [AnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer.html)

Within your AnnotationTransformer implementation, you can basically read up your list of methods, and then inspect each TestNG Test method that comes into your transfomer and change its attributes (In your case, you just need to add the attribute enabled=false) for the @Test annotated method in question if its NOT the method that you are looking for..

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1155871) is a sample annotation transformer implementation that I wrote up sometime back.